Why is -proc:none processing the custom annotations?
I am configuring a CustomAnnotationProcessor in Java 17 in compile time. I found that a way to achieve this is adding an <execution> block  to the pom.xml. The solution shows the usage of
<compilerArgument>-proc:only</compilerArgument> 

As the right way to run the annotation procesors.
The problem is that when I set the -proc:only  I get this error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.13.0:compile (default-compile) on project entity-validator-api-archetype: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Provider com.eva.CustomAnnotationProcessor not found

But if use the -proc:none
<compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>

The annotations are processed.
...
Processing test...
Processing test...
[INFO] Processing: DemoApplication with value: Demo Value
...

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.356 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-09-23T06:56:05-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

What I read is the following:
-proc:none: Disables all annotation processing.
-proc:only: Intended to run only the annotation processors.
Can you explain why it is working like as an inverted way?
Some Java behavior that is not easy to explain.
Files:
CustomAnnotation.java
package com.eva;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE) // Use on classes
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE) // Processed at the source level
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
    String value();
}

CustomAnnotationProcessor.java
package com.eva;


import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.Processor;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedSourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;
import java.util.Set;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.eva.CustomAnnotation") // Annotation to process
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_17) // Java version
public class CustomAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        System.out.println("Processing test...");
        for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(CustomAnnotation.class)) {
            CustomAnnotation annotation = element.getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);

            // Print a message (could be for code generation, validation, etc.)
            processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE,
                    "Processing: " + element.getSimpleName() + " with value: " + annotation.value());

            // You can also generate code or files here using Filer or Trees API
        }
        return true;
    }
}

DemoApplication.java
package com.eva;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@CustomAnnotation("Demo Value")
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}

I added the com.eva.CustomAnnotationProcessor to the javax.annotation.processing.Processor
pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.eva</groupId>
    <artifactId>entity-validator-api-archetype</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.70</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version> <!-- Adjust to the correct version -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.0.Final</version> <!-- Use a compatible version -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                            <includes>
                                <include>com/eva/CustomAnnotationProcessor.java</include>
                                <!--include dependencies required for LogMeCustomAnnotationProcessor -->
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile-project</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


Don’t confuse compiling the annotation processor itself, which can’t use the annotation processor that doesn’t exist yet, with compiling the application using the annotations.

@Holger then you are saying that this is right (using -proc:none) ?

I’m not fluent in reading POMs, but it seem that this is only compiling CustomAnnotationProcessor.java, in that case, yes, it’s correct to specify -proc:none (unless compiling your annotation processor requires other annotation processors). Or remove the entry from the META-INF/… resource that declares this specific annotation processor to the compiler, for this step. I can’t recognize when the compilation of DemoApplication takes place…
